# HTML5 Audio is not looping in Chrome for Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, html5-audio

Used the following snippet to start audio on calling

```
startCallingRingAudio(){
    this.ringAudio = new Audio(this.ringSrc);
    this.ringAudio.loop = true;
    this.ringAudio.play();
}
```

This used to work fine earlier, it stopped working now. Audio does play, but only once. What desired is to make it playing until i stop forcefully by calling

```
stopCallingRingAudio(){
    if(this.ringAudio){
        this.ringAudio.pause();
        this.ringAudio = null;
    }
}
```

I tried with

```
<audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="../assets/sound/ringtone.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

but issue is still same.

The magic is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_loop.asp) demo works fine. And all the above functionality works in firefox well.

Any help?

Comment: Likely related to the other issues lately with Chrome and mp3 and not being able to determine length - without length you can't loop (or trigger proper events for end etc.). I would suggest trying to re-encode the file using a different "mp3" encoder, or to a different format - try f.ex. ogg just for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Working with ogg format.